# Delete too long words in a code

Tags: notepad

I have a list of words in one line, separated by commas and quotation marks, like this:

> "WORD1","WORD2","WORD3"...

I would like to know if I can delete the words that are more long that 9 characters. How can I do this? I can use Notepad++ if needed.

Comment: Is a regex solution with **Notepad++** valid for you?

Comment: yes, it's valid

Comment: See my answer .

Comment: What have you attempted? Regex, powershell, .net, php, VBa...?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powershell to do that:

File test.txt:

```
"xxxxxx7","xxxxxxx8","xxxxxxxx9","xxxxxxxx10","xxxxxxxxx11"
```

Powershell:

```
get-content test.txt | foreach-Object {
  $_.Split(',') 
} | % {if($_.length -lt 12) {$_}} | & {$ofs=',';"$input"} | out-file test2.txt
```

test2.txt:

```
"xxxxxx7","xxxxxxx8","xxxxxxxx9"
```

-lt 12 means lower than 12 (9 chars + 2 quotes = 11)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^"]{10,}",?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           # a double quote
[^"]{10,}   # 10 or more non quote character
"           # a double quote
,?          # an optional comma
```

**Input example:**

```
"word","wordword","wordwordword","word"
```

**Output:**

```
"word","wordword","word"
```